# Bug in Copy Files build phase? Screen Saver copy to Library/Screen Savers

Tags: xcode

Why would a Copy Files build phase fail?  I'm working with Nick Zman's Hyperspace code, and added a Copy Files build phase with an Absolute Path target of "Library/Screen Savers" - the exact same (I think) phase I have in another project (Hypertorus).  Hypertorus compiles fine and installs fine, Hyperspace compiles, but doesn't copy.  The compiled saver does show up in the build/Release directory, but not in Library/Screen Savers.  The error recurs with a fresh download of the source too, which seems odd.  Any ideas, or should I reinstall xCode (or the entire system..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer to this one too which might be of use to someone else.  xCode didn't automatically add the product target under the Copy Files item in the left pane hierarchy.  It does seem a bit strange that if you double click on the Copy Files build phase, the window has an explicit place for the destination, but not the source, since apparently you must be able to put things there other than just the product.